# Update package-lock.json to point package to new repo

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, repo, package-lock.json

I have installed a package through npm which I have edited and uploaded to my own github-repository.

Now I want package.json/package-lock.json to refer to the archive I uploaded to my own github-repo instead of the one I downloaded through npm.

How do I change package-files (package.json and package-lock.json) to read the package from my repo instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install any public node project directly by putting in the link to github.

```
npm i https://github.com/user_name/node_project_name
```